# Multisite: Run a subdomain install from a directory install

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping

Here's what I have.

One main domain example.com which has the wp multisite install at `example.com/school/blog`

I have two other add on domains that I want to run blogs from above multisite installation. So

`foo.com/blog/site1` will run from `example.com/school/blog/site1`

`foo.com/blog/site2` will run from `example.com/school/blog/site2`

`bar.com/blog/site3` will run from `example.com/school/blog/site3`

`bar.com/blog/site4` will run from `example.com/school/blog/site4`

Both foo.com and bar.com already point to example.com/school

So internally the urls all map, but the wp multisite installation sees it as a directory install and won't let me give top level domains to each site. Is there any way around that?

Here's the htaccess that wordpress gave me during installation.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /school/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

and the wp-config

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'achshar.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/school/blog/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Comment: Please add the configuration from `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` to understand the install on example.com.

Comment: @bueltge done :)

Comment: The path inside the installation is `/school/blog`. Also will WP use this as default site path.

Comment: But when I load `foo.com/blog` it redirects to `example.com/blog` and when I load `foo.com/blog/site1` it gives a 404.

Comment: Update the files and the permalinks, there was saved for each site in the settings.